# Regex PHP to find BBCode tag contents

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a string such as this:

```
Land of gray [example]here is an example[/example] and pink.
```

I'm struggling to get the PHP/regex code that will return the contents of the `[example]` tag into a variable...

Comment: How exactly are you struggling?

Comment: PHP has a [BBCode parser](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), so why not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a PHP expert but... this regex will work

```
\[example\]([^\[]*)\[
```

That will capture the contents in the capture group.

So your example contents should be in $matches[1] ???

ex:

```
<?php
$subject = "Land of gray [example]here is an example[/example] and pink.";
$pattern = '/\[example\]([^\[]*)\[/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

I didn't test the code above because I don't have PHP running on this machine but I think that would work...

Comment: It'll probably break on `"Land of gray [example]here is [an example[/example] and pink"` but I'm not sure how you'd want to handle that anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I added the [/youtube] to the regex to make it more solid: $pattern = '/\[youtube\]([^\[]*)\[\/youtube\]/';

Answer (score 0):

BB code allows attributes. [url="somelink"]click[/url] will not be parsed properly with this regex. I would like to give you an answer, but my regex does'nt work well and it's the reason I got here in the first place. Lol. ;-)